# Erro: mysql_fetch_assoc dentro da function

Tags: php, mysql

```
function retornaStatusPesquisa($numeroStatus,$nomePessoa, $nomeTabela){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(status) AS valorStatus FROM $nomeTabela WHERE status=$numeroStatus AND nomePessoa='$nomePessoa'");
    $contador=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $contador;
}
```

Estou recebendo este erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE status=1 AND nomePessoa='Joao'' at line 1

Provavelmente é por causa do `$nomeTabela`, não sei por quais motivos isto ocorre, poderiam dar uma luz?

Answer (score 3):

Existe a possibilidade de você ou alguém estar passando o `$nomePessoa` acrescido de uma aspas simples, exemplo `João'`, e isso acaba quebrando a lógica da sua concatenação de parâmetros além de abrir brechas de segurança.

Prefira passar os parâmetros através do `bindValue`, mais informações aqui: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)

Outra fonte que poderá ajudá-lo a mudar seu projeto para PDO:
http://www.thedevfiles.com/2014/08/moving-from-mysql-query-to-pdo/